# array of strings to tree data structure

Tags: javascript, data-structures, treeview

There is data returned from server containing an array of strings as hierarchy like this:

```
[
 "house.bedroom.bed",
 "house.kitchen.spoon",
 "house.kitchen.knife",
 "house.bedroom.sofa",
 "house.bedroom.tv",
 "plants.trees",
 "house.birds.parrot.grey"
 ...]
```

how do i create a tree data structure out of it to make Output the data in tree form.

like this:

```
root
  house
    bedroom
      bed
      sofa
      tv
    kitchen
      spoon
      knife
    birds
      parrot
        grey
  plants
    trees
```

what is the most simple way to do so ?

and is there any way to reverse it ? for example of asked **knife** i want to return **house.kitchen.knife**

thanks in advance

Comment: please add the wanted structure as javascript array/object? and what you have tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz i have not tried anything yet because i couldn't find any answer for something like this using strings, i tried to separate the ( . ) but i failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take an array with nested arrays where the first element is the name.

For finding a wanted string, it uses a recursive approach by keeping the path to the actual elements for later joining a wanted string.

... right, why an array and not a funky object? Glad that you asked. Arrays allows to maintain a specific order without relying on actual implementation of ordered objects.

```js
function find([key, values], string, temp = []) {
    var result;
    temp = temp.concat(key);
    if (key === string) {
        return temp.slice(1).join('.');
    }
    values.some(a => result = find(a, string, temp));
    return result;
}

var array = ["house.bedroom.bed", "house.kitchen.spoon", "house.kitchen.knife", "house.bedroom.sofa", "house.bedroom.tv", "plants.trees", "house.birds.parrot.grey"],
    result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        ('root.' + s).split('.').reduce((a, item) => {
            var array = a.find(([v]) => v === item);
            if (!array) {
                a.push(array = [item, []]);
            }
            return array[1];
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []).pop();

console.log(find(result, 'knife')); // house.kitchen.knife
console.log(find(result, '42'));    // undefined, what else?
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: worked perfectly is is there any way to reverse it ? for example of asked knife i want to return house.kitchen.knife

Answer (score 4):

```js
const data = [
    "house.bedroom.bed",
    "house.kitchen.spoon",
    "house.kitchen.knife",
    "house.bedroom.sofa",
    "house.bedroom.tv",
    "plants.trees",
    "house.birds.parrot.grey"
];

const mainMapFromStart = {};
const mainMapFromEnd = {};
function set(parts, mainMap) {
    let map = mainMap;
    for(const item of parts) {
        map[item] = map[item] || {};
        map = map[item];
    }
}

data.map(item => item.split('.')).forEach(parts => {
    set(parts, mainMapFromStart);
    set(parts.reverse(), mainMapFromEnd);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(mainMapFromStart, null, 4));
console.log(JSON.stringify(mainMapFromEnd, null, 4));
```

This code will return this structure in mainMap in both ways:

```
output:
{
    "house": {
        "bedroom": {
            "bed": {},
            "sofa": {},
            "tv": {}
        },
        "kitchen": {
            "spoon": {},
            "knife": {}
        },
        "birds": {
            "parrot": {
                "grey": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "plants": {
        "trees": {}
    }
}
{
    "bed": {
        "bedroom": {
            "house": {}
        }
    },
    "spoon": {
        "kitchen": {
            "house": {}
        }
    },
    "knife": {
        "kitchen": {
            "house": {}
        }
    },
    "sofa": {
        "bedroom": {
            "house": {}
        }
    },
    "tv": {
        "bedroom": {
            "house": {}
        }
    },
    "trees": {
        "plants": {}
    },
    "grey": {
        "parrot": {
            "birds": {
                "house": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly is is there any way to reverse it ? for example of asked knife i want to return house.kitchen.knife

Comment: Sure, for this you should use a reverse map as well. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

here's one way to do it, might not be the most efficient, but works. If you don't want the leafs as empty objects, you can modify it as needed.

```
var r=[
 "house.bedroom.bed",
 "house.kitchen.spoon",
 "house.kitchen.knife",
 "house.bedroom.sofa",
 "house.bedroom.tv",
 "plants.trees",
 "house.birds.parrot.grey"];

var o={}; // output object
function build(o,p){
 p.split(".").forEach(function(d){
   o = o[d] || (o[d]={});  
 });
}    

r.forEach(function(a,i){ // build up each branch based on path
 build(o, a);
});
o
```

Comment: worked perfectly is is there any way to reverse it ? for example of asked knife i want to return house.kitchen.knife

Answer (score -2):

Code below will give you the last string that includes the keyword. Let me know if this wasn't what you were looking for.

```js
let stringsArray = [
  "house.bedroom.bed",
  "house.kitchen.spoon",
  "house.kitchen.knife",
  "house.bedroom.sofa",
  "house.bedroom.tv",
  "plants.trees",
  "house.birds.parrot.grey"
];

function findInArray() {
let keyword = document.getElementById('search').value;
  let results = document.getElementById('results');
  stringsArray.forEach(function(string, index) {
    if (string.includes(keyword)) {
      results.innerHTML = string;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="search">Search for:</label>
<input type="text" id="search">
<button type="button" onclick='findInArray()'>Search</button>

<span id="results"></span>
```