# Create Node Structure From Tree Structure

Tags: typescript

I currently have a structure like this

```
{

    "A1": {
        "B1": {
            "C1": {},
            "C2": {}
        },
        "B2": {
            "C2": {}
        }
    },
    "A2": {}
}
```

And I want something like this

```js
[

 {
   name: A1,
   child:[ {
            name: B1,
            child:[
                    {
                        name: C1,
                        child:[]
                    },
                    {
                        name: C2,
                        child:[]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
            name: B2,
            child:[
                    {
                        name: C1,
                        child:[]
                    },
                    {
                        name: C2,
                        child:[]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
 },
 {
   name: A1,
   child:[] 
 }
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an object from a JSON file structure, some other input, etc. and are you needing an generic object as output, or are you trying to do something more specific with it?

Comment: trying to create an object from JSON object structure.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into?

Comment: I have an string array like this ["A1", 'A1#B1',"A1#B1:C1"], Wanted to create node tree without recursion. I am able to create tree with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661889/array-of-strings-to-tree-data-structure/51662337#51662337 post.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a recursive function using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to map over the key-value pairs of each sub-structure in your tree:

```js
const myTree = {
  A1: {
    B1: {
      C1: {},
      C2: {}
    },
    B2: {
      C2: {}
    }
  },
  A2: {}
};

function treeToNode (tree) {
  return Object.entries(tree).map(
    ([key, value]) => ({
      name: key,
      child: treeToNode(value)
    })
  );
}

console.log(treeToNode(myTree));
```

Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51661889/1541563), if you wanted to skip the intermediate step of generating a tree, you could convert the array of delimited strings directly to a node, using a helper class that extends [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const myHierarchy = [
  'house.bedroom.bed',
  'house.kitchen.spoon',
  'house.kitchen.knife',
  'house.bedroom.sofa',
  'house.bedroom.tv',
  'neighbor.house',
  'plants.trees',
  'house.birds.parrot.grey'
];

class NodeMap extends Map {
  static fromHierarchy (hierarchy) {
    return hierarchy.reduce(
      (node, id) => (
        id.split('.').reduce(
          (node, key) => node.add(key),
          node
        ),
        node
      ),
      new NodeMap()
    );
  }

  add (key) {
    const value = this.get(key) || new NodeMap();
    this.set(key, value);
    return value;
  }

  search (id) {
    return Array.from(this).flatMap(
      ([key, value]) => [
        ...(key === id ? [key] : []),
        ...value.search(id).map(
          rest => [key, rest].join('.')
        )
      ]
    );
  }

  toJSON () {
    return Array.from(this).map(
      ([key, value]) => ({
        name: key,
        child: value
      })
    );
  }
}

const myNode = NodeMap.fromHierarchy(myHierarchy);

console.log(myNode.search('knife'));
console.log(myNode.search('birds'));
console.log(myNode.search('house'));
console.log(myNode.search('flowers'));
console.log(myNode);
```

`search()` returns an array of results in case there are multiple matches, such as `house` in the example.