# array of strings to tree data structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, tree, hierarchy

There is data returned from server containing an array of strings as hierarchy like this:

```
var array = [
 "house.bedroom.bed",
 "house.kitchen.spoon",
 "house.kitchen.knife",
 "house.bedroom.sofa",
 "house.bedroom.tv",
 "plants.trees",
 "house.birds.parrot.grey"
 ]
```

i have successful made a tree data structure as object out of it to make Output the data in tree form below:

```
  house
    bedroom
      bed
      sofa
      tv
    kitchen
      spoon
      knife
    birds
      parrot
        grey
  plants
    trees
```

and is there any way to pick a string? for example of asked "kitchen" i want to return all related to that string like this:

```
house.kitchen.knife
house.kitchen.spoon
```

Here the codes that i learned:

```
function find([key, values], string, temp = []) {
    var result;
    temp = temp.concat(key);
    if (key === string) {
        return temp.slice(1).join('.');
    }
    values.some(a => result = find(a, string, temp));
    return result;
}


var result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        ('root.' + s).split('.').reduce((a, item) => {
            var array = a.find(([v]) => v === item);
            if (!array) {
                a.push(array = [item, []]);
            }
            return array[1];
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []).pop();

console.log(find(result, 'kitchen'));
console.log(result);
```

my output is:

```
house.kitchen
```

Comment: I think you just need to filter source array `array.filter((path) => path.split('.').includes('kitchen'))`

Comment: i tried that it worked perfect but the goal is i need to turn the array = [] output to object to satisfy the tree data structure and then i apply find() function to find match parent and children related "kitchen"........
i made the tree but not able to run find() to match parent and children of "kitchen" to satisfy expected output

Comment: You have a function that make a tree from an array. Just make the tree from the filtered array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array of strings to tree data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661889/array-of-strings-to-tree-data-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to filter the original array

```js
const data = ["house.bedroom.bed","house.kitchen.spoon", "house.kitchen.knife","house.bedroom.sofa","house.bedroom.tv",
 "plants.trees","house.birds.parrot.grey"];
 
 
 const result = data.filter((path) => path.split('.').includes('kitchen'));
 
 console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: actually this solution is helpful but i will need to research more to print out same result of your output from my tree data sctructure not from given data file

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you're asking. I would solve this problem with recursion.

```
function parse(items) {
   return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const k = item.slice(0, item.indexOf('.'))
      const v = item.slice(item.indexOf('.') + 1).split('.')
      
      const newItem = {
        [k]: v.length > 1 ? parse(v) : v
      }

      return Object.assign(acc, newItem)
   }, { })
}
```

This is not a complete solution but should get the general idea across. For each item in the array, split it off into a key and a value. The key will be the string before the first `.`, and the value with either be the single string after that `.`, or an object containing children.

Comment: hi.. thank you for your help. how should i set this recursion???

Comment: what you are asking is almost a backtracking solution. There is no relative ordering to the elements in the array and this would only complicate things. A simple scan through the array should work better. Or you could modify your tree object to include the complete path at the leaf level.

Comment: I imagine this could be made to be very simple with some effort. You could be right, but this to me seems like a great opportunity for recursion because the problem is fractal. What was done for `"house.bedroom.bed"` must be done again for `"bedroom.bed"`.